# Flutter Image getting black and red like below image when i adjust the screen size

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-web

**This happens in web only on adjusting screen**[image]

```
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/rsoft_logo.png'),
                    height: 130,
                    width: 130),
```

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. And you can use `fit` property on image.

Comment: tried plenty of times bro, not solved

Comment: I face this issue as well. It is not happening on Desktop (macOS) but it is on Web. I tried adding errorBuilder to the Image widget with no luck. Everything seems fine. Neither AssetImage nor NetworkImage works. Adding a color to the image correctly prints the color on top of the gradient... I believe this should be reported in the Github issues: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I switched to the **master** channel of Flutter and it works perfectly now. It *seems* that it was a bug fixed in a recent release of the Flutter master channel.

Check the Flutter version below:

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.11.0-0.0.pre.691, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

**When did it happen for me?**

At first, it happened on one image after playing a while with Chrome's window. Then it happened with all of my images just after starting to drag the Chrome's window.

I tried to check what was causing this with the Image widget itself but everything seemed right and nothing explained the gradient.

Today, it didn't happen on first launch (after a reboot), but happened just after a hot reload and and on next launches.

I updated Android Studio, rebooted again, etc, but nothing worked. The gradient appeared pretty fast on some images (not always all).

Switching to **master** channel solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter needs time to load the assets, so it is preferred to pre-cache the assets.

Try adding

```
@override
  void initState() {
    precacheImage(AssetImage('assets/rsoft_logo.png'));
    super.initState();
  }
```

NOTE: make sure you have the stateful widget as we are using state here.

Comment: Not works bro, Is there any other way ?

Comment: are you getting any logs in terminal

Comment: try using `Image.asset` or `Image.network` instead `Image`

Comment: Image.asset(
                      'assets/rsoft_logo.png',
                      height: 130,
                      width: 130,
                    ),

Comment: this also causing same error. This is my anydesk id 451 156 111 can u fix this bro.

Comment: unable to figure out the issue bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241486/discussion-between-nagendra-nag-and-anandh-krishnan).

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan ok done. leb1755's solution isn't useful for you?

Comment: no bro ,not works